# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/fn/array' React Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, core-js

I changed CollectionPage's component to arrow function component rather than just normal function and then I got this error but I don't know why it didn't threw this error when I did the same with a lot of other components .
this the comonent code

```
import { from } from 'core-js/fn/array'
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import Products from '../Products/Products'
import {H1} from '../../Style/global'

const CollectionPage=()=> {
    const {collectionTitle}= useParams()
    return (
        <div style={{marginTop:96}}>
            <H1>{collectionTitle} Collection</H1>
            <Products collectionTitle={collectionTitle}/>
        </div>
    )
}


export default CollectionPage
```

btw this a react webpack project and here is my webpack config :

```
const path = require('path')
const HTMLPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports ={
    entry :"./src/index.js",
    output:{
        path:path.resolve(__dirname,"./dist"),
        filename:'index.js',
    },
    plugins:[
        new HTMLPlugin({template:'./src/index.html'}),
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
              { from: './src/images', to: 'images' },
            ],
          }),
    ],
    module:{
        rules:[
            { 
                test : /\.js$/,
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                use:{
                    loader:"babel-loader"
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|gif|jpg)$/,
                include: [
                  path.join(__dirname, './src/images')
                ],
                loader: 'file-loader',
             },
            {
                test:/.(png|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|gif)$/, //Customise according to your need
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                      limit: 100000000,
                    }
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                use: ['source-map-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' 
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

this is the error :

> ./src/components/routes/CollectionPage.js Module not found: Error:
> Can't resolve 'core-js/fn/array' in 'C:\Users\Ora
> Ora\l-3afya-mafya-merch-store-react-js-\src\components\routes'

also getting this error

> Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or
> locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp' Error from chokidar
> (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat
> 'C:\hiberfil.sys' Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY:
> resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys' Error from chokidar
> (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat
> 'C:\swapfile.sys' Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY:
> resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp' Error from
> chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked,
> lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys' Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error:
> EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys' Error from
> chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked,
> lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'

Comment: Is the name of the module that you tried to import “from”. `import { from } from 'core-js/fn/array'`. It shouldn’t be something like `import { array } from 'core-js/fn/array'`?

Comment: @JacoboTapia omg I swear to god  didn't see that import I guess this is a stupid visual studio auto import ,waw I scanned to component for hours . thank you

Comment: NP, sometimes is good an extra pair of eyes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

thanks to Jacobo Tapia's comment  I realized that  this was a stupid visual studio auto importing error as you can see on top of my component there this import `import { from } from 'core-js/fn/array'` which doesn't make any sense

Comment: i lost a fkcing hour of work trying to debug this exact problem 

Comment: lol me to its freaking annoying visual studio code does this a lot , just three days ago it happened to me again

Comment: looks like I was not alone to face this annoying vs code feature

Comment: yeah man especially if you have a big  codebase like I had , god luck finding the bug